# Wick's theorem: Classical Version. Derivation question.

Tags: statistics

I am trying to prove the classical version of Wick's theorem:

For a set of random variables ${a_i}$, with covariance matrix $M$ and $\rho(\vec a)$ a Gaussian probabilitiy density: 
$$\langle a_j a_k a_m a_n \rangle = M_{jk} \langle a_m a_n \rangle+ M_{jm} \langle  a_k a_n\rangle+ M_{jn} \langle  a_k a_m \rangle $$

which can then be generalized to higher moments. I am trying to prove the relation that one needs to prove this:

$$ (a_j-\bar a_j)\rho(\vec a)=-\sum_k M_{j,k}{\partial \over \partial a_k } \rho(\vec a)$$

And I would really like to get this part of the derivation:
$${\partial \over \partial a_k } \rho(\vec a)={\partial \over \partial a_k }e^{-{1 \over 2} \sum \limits_{i,j} (a_i-\bar a_i)M_{i,j}^{-1}(a_j-\bar a_j)}$$
using the product rule on the sum representation of exp I get
$${\partial \over \partial a_k }\sum \limits_{i,j} (a_i-\bar a_i)M_{i,j}^{-1}(a_j-\bar a_j)=\sum \limits_{j} M_{k,j}^{-1}(a_j-\bar a_j)+\sum \limits_{i} (a_i-\bar a_i)M_{i,k}^{-1}$$
which gives me:

$$ (a_j-\bar a_j)\rho(\vec a)=\sum_k M_{j,k}\sum \limits_{l} M_{k,l}^{-1}(a_l-\bar a_l)\rho(\vec a)=\sum \limits_{l} (a_l-\bar a_l)\rho(\vec a)$$

which is not right. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: How did you simply fhe sum over matrix indices in the last line? It should be $ \sum_{k} M_{j,k} M^{-1} _{k,l} = \delta_{j,l} $. Then summing over $ l$ changes it to a j.

Comment: Sound reasonable.I just noticed the equation I started with contains something very confusing to me: The left side is a scalar and the right side a vector right? EDIT: no they are components of a vector on the left = scalars and components on the right ! Okay cheers ^^

Comment: You're on to something: for example, the last equation does not even make sense because there is a free index $ j $ on the left side, but all indices bound on the right side.

Comment: What I was trying to say was thank you I get it now. i was confused about my own notation as it appears^^